# Determine What Custom Site Template A Site Was Created From

Tags: development

Hey SharePointateers,

I've hit a problem I've given up on solving, so I've decided to cheat and ask here. If this doesn't work I might have to do something drastic like read a manual or something.

So I've used "Site Settings" to "Save a site as a template" then created a couple of sites using that template.

Now I want my C# to be able to identify sites created with that custom site template. SPWeb's .WebTemplate, .WebTemplateId and .Configuration are not use to me because they all come back as "STS", 1 and 1.

I think this might because they are concerned with the underlying SharePoint template as opposed to custom templates. This is probably one of those ambiguous term thingies that keep biting me in this space.

I guess I could always add my own artifact to the original site that I then save as a custom template, and then just search for that, but there must be something already there because if I remove the custom site template then try to save a site I had previously created from it as a new custom site template, SharePoint errors.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. Exactly what error do you experience in your test? Tracking down that exception via reflector could provide some light in how SharePoint can track the template name.

Comment: Also, about the "Template" wording. Usually the STS#1 kind of templates are called "Definitions", but even Microsoft today use random naming, so that's the cause of the confusion.

Comment: (Oops. Sorry about the Meta thing. I got there from a google search "Best Place to post SharePoint Questions" and thought the Meta thing was just for uniqueness. Something like "Data About SharePoint" as opposed to "Data About A WebSite About SherePoint". Hmmm... there's not way I can talk myself out of this embaressment, is there?)

Comment: There is no exception. It's just the properties are all the same value regardless of whether the site is created with the custom template or not. I breaked (or is it broken) the code at the point of checking and there is no other obvious property that helps either.  There's no sign of the custom site template in the "STS" folder in the hive, and the clue might be that custom site template appears in the "Solution Gallery", and thus internally called a solution. I could browse it with PowerShell at SPSite.Solutions so as far as the object model is concerned it's a SPUserSolution.

Comment: I was refering to *"there must be something already there because if I remove the custom site template then try to save a site I had previously created from it as a new custom site template, SharePoint errors"* - does the error include anything that could be helpfull to pinpoint where the exception is thrown? As I said before, the idea was to use Reflector/ILSpy/DotPeek/JustDecompile etc to try to find where that error is raised: if we are lucky we may find out how SharePoint seems to recognize that the site has been created from a saved template.

Comment: Sorry. I discovered that issue about 6 months ago so wasn't really thinking about it. But this is a very good point. I'll recreate and see how I go. From memory it was in SolutionExporter which is not simple code, but I suppose it's about time I bit the bullet and learned how it works.

Comment: Had a look at it, only things that I notice are some checks related to workflow. Maybe these were the cause of the error?

Comment: I have this same need and was wondering if you ever solved it?

Comment: Hi dscarr. I never had time to pursue the cause of the exception. Instead I took one approach for 2010 and a different approach in 2013 though both may work with either version. In 2010 we had a web template solution that had a stapled feature with an event receiver that created custom properties in the SPWeb and used a custom web part to list the sites. In 2013 I embedded <meta> tags into the home page that could be picked up by a Search Results web part. Hope this is of some help.